# Slick-Slider image inside a div container not resize based windows size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

I use slick-slider at my website to show the 6 newest posts. Normally, on slick-slider content, there are image, post title, category, share and so on (I refer to [iflscience homepage](http://www.iflscience.com/)).

The problem is, if the image is put exact after slick-slider, the image size will responsive to window size.

**I am using 2 slideToShow Setting that will reponsive to 1 slideToShow after below certain width at slick-slider**

```html
<div class="container-body">
  <div class="slider your-class">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg"/>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg"/>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg"/>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg"/>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg"/>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

But if I create a container to warp the post newest post content, the image size wouldn't responsive to window size.

```html
<div class="container-body">
  <div class="slider your-class">
    <div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg"/>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the image inside the "div" is dynamically changed like when I didn't use "div".

I have tried to create a script to dynamically change the image width with `height: auto`, but sometime it doesn't work and depend on how fast we are resizing.

I understand, the div size will depend on image size, so the slick slider height won't change at all. But I haven't any clues to solve it.

Comment: width: 100%; display: inline-block;

Comment: Hai Joe Warner, thanks for the answer, since i use 2 images every slideshow, i think it will not able to use it. And for addition, it will use 1 image when size reduce bellow some value. Thanks

Comment: yes you can i'll futher my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Div's default `display` is `block`, `img` default position is `inline` we can resolve this by setting the container to inline or inline block and setting the width to `100%`

I've got a loop that sets the width of the img-con and the width of the img container.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.con').forEach(el => {
  el.style.width = `${el.children.length * 100}%`;
  Array.from(el.children).forEach(img => {
    img.style.width = `${100 / el.children.length}%`
  })
})
```

```css
.slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 50%;
}

.img-con {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.con {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
}

.img-con>img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.img-con:before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 64%;
  display: block;
}

.container-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-body">
  <div class="slider your-class active">
    <div class="con">
      <div class="img-con">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="img-con">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="img-con">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="img-con">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="img-con">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="img-con">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slider your-class active">
    <div class="con">
      <div class="img-con">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="img-con">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="img-con">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="img-con">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="img-con">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="img-con">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have tried it, i use 2 slidesToShow, when i resize the window from the right, the image on right-side move and cover the left-side, but no responsive to resize at all. Sorry if i missed something :D, Thanks Joe

Comment: Yeah, i am so sorry Joe :D

Comment: No worries i've updated using flex please tell me if this is what you're looking for

Comment: Its working very perfectly Joe. Many Thanks 

Last consideration. Since you use 50vw, when # slideToShow is 1, the image only 50% of the page and left whitespace. Can we use any alternative to 50vw so it will responsive to # slideToShow, or we must use a script to determine it?

Thanks Joe

Comment: I've set two sliders side by side to match that site. yeah there are ways but my lunch break is over now when i get a moment i'll update

Comment: one question will there always be two items or could there be a dynamic amount per slide

Comment: For my further knowledge, i hope you show me a dynamic amount, so we can manipulate it freely. Thanks Joe

Comment: hacked together something properly not the best solution but a bit busy, i'll properly come back and improve.